Evaluating $\int e^{x^4} (\cos(x)-x^3) dx$
I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int e^{x^4} (\cos(x)-x^3) dx$$

Since $\int e^{x^4} (\cos(x)-x^3) dx=\int e^{x^4}\cos(x)dx-\int x^3 e^{x^4} dx$ and clearly $\int x^3 e^{x^4}dx=\frac{e^{x^4}}{4}+C$ the real challenge is evaluating $\int e^{x^4} \cos(x) dx$. To do so I first tried the substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ but it got me nowhere so I also tried the substitution $x=t^{\frac{1}{4}}$ whereby I obtained
$$ \int e^{x^4}\cos(x)dx=\int e^t \frac{\cos(t^{\frac{1}{4}})}{4 t^{3/4}}  dt. $$  I then tried to evaluate this integral by parts by setting $f=e^t$ and $dg=\frac{\cos(t^{\frac{1}{4}})}{4 t^{3/4}}$ and I obtained $$\int e^t \frac{\cos(t^{\frac{1}{4}})}{4 t^{3/4}} dt=e^t \sin(t^{1/4})-\int e^t \sin(t^{1/4})dt. $$ Now, I tried to evaluate $\int e^t \sin(t^{1/4})dt$ again by parts but by setting $dg=e^t$ and $f=\sin(t^{1/4})$ I got nowhere (more precisely, I got $0=0$) and if I tried $f=e^t$ and $dg=\sin(t^{1/4})$ then I would have to integrate $\sin(t^{1/4})$ which would be troublesome.
At this point I have run out of ideas so I would be grateful if someone would give me some advice on how to evaluate this integral. Thanks

Where did this integral come from? Wolfram only gives me a series expansion, and based on the integrand, I don't think the antiderivative is elementary.

@SeanRoberson I got it from some calculus notes, in which it is listed as a challenge exercise(!)

If you can, check the notes for errata, or a solution you can differentiate. A misprint is likely.

If we exclude series solutions, the maximum exponent of the exponential is $2$ and not higher
